# How to trigger loading animation from a loading action in react/redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, axios

I am developing my first react/redux web app that fetches concerts from an external api. I have several actions in my action creator regarding this including, `"LOADING_CONCERTS", "GET_CONCERTS", AND "SET_CONCERTS"`. I then render these concerts in a concert list component. Is it possible to add a loading bar component to render while redux is on the loading action? Some code:

my async axios:

```
export const getConcerts = (artist) => {
      return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'LOADING_CONCERTS' });
        return axios.get(${api_url})
          .then(concerts => {
            dispatch({ type: 'GET_CONCERTS', concerts })
            dispatch({ type: 'SET_CONCERTS', concerts })
            dispatch(addReviewsToConcerts(concerts))
          })
          .catch( err=> {
            console.log(err.code)
            console.log(err.message)
            console.log(err.stack)
          }
          )
        }
    }
```

my reducer:

```
const initialState = []

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOADING_CONCERTS':
      return state;
    case 'GET_CONCERTS':
      return action.concerts.data
    case 'ADD_REVIEWS_TO_CONCERTS':
      return action.concerts
    case 'SAVE_CONCERT':
      return action
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

the concerts container:

```
import React from 'react';
import ConcertSearchFormWrapper from './ConcertSearchFormWrapper';
import ConcertsList from '../.././components/concerts/ConcertsList';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const Concerts = (props) => {
    return (
      <div className="concerts-container">
        <ConcertSearchFormWrapper />
        { (props.concerts.length > 0 && props.concerts !== '\n{warn=Not found}\n') ? <ConcertsList /> : null}
      </div>
    )
};

export default connect((state) => ({ concerts: state.concerts })) (Concerts);
```

and then the list component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { saveConcert } from '../.././actions/concerts/concerts'




const ConcertsList = ({concerts, saveConcert}) => {

    const date = (datetime) => {
      return new Date(datetime).toDateString()
    }

    return (

      <div className = "concerts-list">

        {concerts.sort((a, b) => (a.datetime < b.datetime) ? 1 : -1).map(c => <><Link key={c.id} to={`/concerts/${c.id}`}  onClick={()=>saveConcert(c)}>{c.lineup[0]} at {c.venue.name} on {date(c.datetime)}</Link><br/></>)}
      </div> 
    )
}



const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {

      concerts: state.concerts
  }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, {saveConcert})(ConcertsList))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to add a loading spinner or a loading bar

1. update your innitial state to include a loding indicator ( for example 'isLoading' boolean.

`const initialState = { isLoading: false, concerts: [], reviews: [] };`

2. Change your case statments to properly update the state on each action , below is roughly how I do it

```
const concertReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOADING_CONCERTS":
      return { ...state, isLoading: true };
    case "GET_CONCERTS":
      return { ...state,
               concerts: action.payload,
               isLoading: false };
    case "ADD_REVIEWS_TO_CONCERTS":
      return { ...state,
              reviews: action.payload };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default concertReducer;
```

3. bring in the isLoading prop to your component using connect and mapStateToProps
4. use ternary operator to check if 'isLoading' is true and conditionally render your spinner or loading bar as follows

```
 {props.isLoading ? (
                <YourLoadinBarHere' />
              ) : (
                <Component or something to render when isLoading is false/>
              )}
```

Now, your loading bar will be displayed while the data is fetching (`props.isLoading == true`)
of course there are other solutions like using HOC pattern but this is how I usually do it.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a shot now.